# Handle Back button in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I would like to finish() the app whenever I press the back button, when the dilog builder is shown.

I have the following code

```
private void displaydialog() 
{
    final LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View settingsview = inflator.inflate(R.layout.nointernet, null);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.reminderalert);
    builder.setTitle("No Network...");
    builder.setView(settingsview);

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();
}
```

I am not sure where to insert the OnKeylistener and Key Event. Can somebody guide me on when/how to insert the listener?

Thanks!

Comment: set a -ve button and in that call onBackPressed().. Override BackPressed(){ finish();}

Comment: This will show up a button on the dialog box. Which I don't want to show. I would like directly handle the back button when the dialog box is shown. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to finish the current `Activity` when `Negative` `Button` of `AlertDialog` is clicked or hardware back button is clicked(when `AlertDialog` is shown) then do something like below,

```
pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // if from activity
                finish();

            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Spring Breaker. That was easy!

Answer (score 1):

use this ... 
when you are press back button this method handle to finish your current activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        finish();

        return true;
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set a `onBackPressed();` and in that call `onBackPressed()`..

```
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           // User cancelled the dialog
onBackPressed();
       }
   });


 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     finish();
 }
```

Comment: This will show up a button on the dialog box. Which I don't want to show. I would like directly handle the back button when the dialog box is shown. Is this possible?